# Test endpoint with HTTP GET

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, testing

I would like to test the endpoint if the response and HTTP code are correct. The controller method looks like this:

```
@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/{ruleId}")
public Rule loadOneRule(@PathVariable String ruleId) {
    return rulesService.loadOneRule(ruleId);
}
```

The test method is

```
@Test
public void loadOneRule() throws IOException, URISyntaxException { 
    NodeDTO nodeDto = new NodeDTO();
    HashMap<String, NodeDTO> nodes = new HashMap<>();
    nodes.put("foo", nodeDto);

    Rule rule = new Rule("my rule", nodes);
    RuleService ruleService = new RuleService();
    rule = ruleService.saveRule(rule);
    String id = rule.getId().toString();

    String target = "http://localhost:8090" + "/v2/rules/" + id; 

    URI uri = new URI(target);
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(uri.toASCIIString());

    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
    int HTTPcode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    String json = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Rule targetRule = objectMapper.readValue(json, Rule.class);

    boolean correctStatus = HTTPcode >= 200 && HTTPcode <= 300 ? true : false;
    boolean correctResponse = targetRule != null ? true : false;

    assertTrue(correctStatus);
    assertTrue(correctResponse);

}
```

I get nullpointer exception on my ruleService. It is the same even if I try to @Autowire it and not instantiate it. I guess the whole approach about getting one rule object from the mongo database is wrong, but putting an object locally in my database and getting this object by his id would be even worse, since these tests will not run on my computer.

This is the exception if I try to autowire my service

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.%%%%.^^^^.controller.v2.test.RuleControllerTest.loadOneRule(RuleControllerTest.java:96)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
at org.junit.vintage.engine.execution.RunnerExecutor.execute(RunnerExecutor.java:42)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(Unknown Source)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(Unknown Source)
at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.executeAllChildren(VintageTestEngine.java:83)
at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.execute(VintageTestEngine.java:74)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:170)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:154)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:90)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:538)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)
```

Comment: Don't create an instance of the `RuleService` ou will need to auto wired one. If you still get exceptions post that exception. Any reason you aren't simply using the `RestTemplate` or `MockMvc` to test your controller?

Comment: @M.Deinum They said it would be easier not to mock al the objects. I am running my project locally and successfully made 3 tests for HTTP GET but this one looks trickier since I must have the object in database to get it's mongo id so the URL to end on this String . I did try to autowire the ruleService and I have the same problem with nullpointer  exception on same line of code.

Comment: Where do I state you need to mock all your objects? Post the null pointer and your actual testcase.

Comment: @M.Deinum I am running my project so tomcat listens on this port I run my test as junit test and added the exception I get if service is autowired

Comment: Well then creating or auto wiring the `RuleService` will not work/help. You need to retrieve a rule that us available at the server not local to your test.

Comment: @M.Deinum Is it possible in my test to create java mongodb object instance and put a rule in the mongo database and then retrieve it ? Should I try to achieve it ?

Comment: No. As your service is running on tomcat and not local to your test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need make request using HttpClient, rather you can use @WebMVCTest to test your controller. One more thing, you don't need to specify the dependencies by creating objects rather mock them using @MockBean. In code below you specify the exact controller name within @WebMvcTest annotation.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(value = YourController.class, secure = false)
public class YourControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private StudentService rulesService;

    Rule mockRule = new Rule();


    @Test
    public void testLoadOneRule() throws Exception {

        Mockito.when(
                rulesService.loadOneRule(Mockito.anyString(),
                        Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(mockCourse);

        RequestBuilder requestBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders.get(
                "/{ruleId}","rule1")

        MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(requestBuilder).andReturn();

        System.out.println(result.getResponse());
        String expected = "{id:rule1,name:'RuleName'}";

        JSONAssert.assertEquals(expected, result.getResponse()
                .getContentAsString(), false);
    }

}
```